# Alternate method Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes in native C++

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, unicode

Need implement `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` in native `C++`.

`.NET` implementation:

```
Console.WriteLine("codePage number: " + Encoding.Unicode.CodePage.ToString());
Console.Write("string: ");
foreach (var ch in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("string"))
    Console.Write(ch.ToString("X") + "-");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("строка: ");
foreach (var ch in Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("строка"))
    Console.Write(ch.ToString("X") + "-");
Console.ReadLine();
```

`.NET` implementation output:

```
codePage number: 1200 
string: 73-0-74-0-72-0-69-0-6E-0-67-0 
строка: 41-4-42-4-40-4-3E-4-3A-4-30-4
```

How implement this method (without use boost, QT, etc..) to C++?

---

I found this method from `Windows`:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

std::wstring ConvertToUTF16(const std::string & source, const UINT codePage)
{
    // Fail if an invalid input character is encountered
    static const DWORD conversionFlags = MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS;

    // Require size for destination string
    int utf16Length = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        codePage,           // code page for the conversion
        conversionFlags,    // flags
        source.c_str(),     // source string
        source.length(),    // length (in chars) of source string
        NULL,               // unused - no conversion done in this step
        0                   // request size of destination buffer, in wchar_t's
    );
    if (utf16Length == 0)
    {
        const DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::exception(
            "MultiByteToWideChar() failed: Can't get length of destination UTF-16 string.",
            error);
    }

    // Allocate room for destination string
    std::wstring utf16Text;
    utf16Text.resize(utf16Length);

    // Convert to Unicode
    if (!::MultiByteToWideChar(
        codePage,           // code page for conversion
        0,                  // validation was done in previous call
        source.c_str(),     // source string
        source.length(),    // length (in chars) of source string
        &utf16Text[0],      // destination buffer
        utf16Text.length()  // size of destination buffer, in wchar_t's
    ))
    {
        const DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
        throw std::exception(
            "MultiByteToWideChar() failed: Can't convert to UTF-16 string.",
            error);
    }

    return utf16Text;
}

void main()
{
    try
    {
        // ASCII text
        std::string inText("string");

        // Unicode
        static const UINT codePage = 1200;

        // Convert to Unicode
        const std::wstring utf16Text = ConvertToUTF16(inText, codePage);

        // Show result
        for (size_t i = 0; i < utf16Text.size(); i++)
            printf("%X-", utf16Text[i]);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "*** ERROR:\n";
        std::cerr << e.what();
        std::cerr << std::endl;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

but `MultiByteToWideChar` no return string size for 1200 code page (`Unicode`).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: @NicolBolas, i read over topics, answers - not help me.

Comment: I have tried a lot of different methods, I can show the my developments if needed.

Comment: Are you sure you need that conversion? In many (but not all) cases where you need to provide a string encoded in UTF-16  in Windows, you could already get UTF-16 from the source of the string.

Comment: The first two statements of your `main()` function are inconsistent. Also, if you follow the documentation for MultiByteToWideChar you'll find code page 1200: "available only to managed applications".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codepage parameter of `MultiByteToWideChar()` specifies the encoding of the **input** `char` data so it can be converted **FROM** that encoding **TO** UTF-16. You never use codepage 1200 in Win32 programming.

Strings in .NET are encoded in UTF-16. `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` returns a UTF-16LE encoded byte array.  So the character data is returned as-is as bytes.

For UTF-16 on Windows, use `wchar_t` or `char16_t` based strings (like `std::wstring` or `std::u16string`). If you need a UTF-16 encoded byte array, allocate `2 * length` bytes (such as with  a `std::vector`) and copy the raw string characters as-is:

```
std::vector<BYTE> GetUnicodeBytes(const std::wstring &str)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> result;
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        result.resize(sizeof(wchar_t) * str.length());
        CopyMemory(&result[0], str.c_str(), result.size());
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
std::wcout << L"string: ";
for (auto ch: GetUnicodeBytes(L"string"))
    std::wcout << std::hex << (int)ch << L"-";
std::wcout << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"строка: ";
for (auto ch: GetUnicodeBytes(L"строка"))
    std::wcout << std::hex << (int)ch << L"-";
std::wcout << std::endl;
```

Alternatively:

```
std::vector<BYTE> GetUnicodeBytes(const std::u16string &str)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> result;
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        result.resize(sizeof(char16_t) * str.length());
        CopyMemory(&result[0], str.c_str(), result.size());
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
std::wcout << L"string: ";
for (auto ch: GetUnicodeBytes(u"string"))
    std::wcout << std::hex << (int)ch << L"-";
std::wcout << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"строка: ";
for (auto ch: GetUnicodeBytes(u"строка"))
    std::wcout << std::hex << (int)ch << L"-";
std::wcout << std::endl;
```